# Python Cx_Freeze error in Windows XP

Tags: python, windows-xp, cx-freeze

I have used cx_freeze several times in my windows 7 and I had never any problem with it but now I want to run the executable produced by cx_freeze in a Windows XP.
But when I run the program I get this error:

`the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling this application may fix this problem`

I have searched for info about this problem and it seems to be the that the Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 redistributable is not intstalled. I am going to launch this executable in many computers so I don't want to install absolutelly nothing in the system.
I have read that I can just place those 4 files in the same folder than my binary is:
Those 3 from this directory

> C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_x-ww_d08d0375
>
> msvcm90.dll msvcp90.dll msvcr90.dll

And this file from this directory

> C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests
>
> x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_x-ww_d08d0375.manifest

I have search this direcories in my system (Win 8) and they are not with this exactly folder. Anyway I downloaded them from internet and try it but it did not work
I have Python 2.7 and cx_Freeze-4.3.1

I have read that if I use a lower version of pyython it could works. It is true? Why?

Do you know hoy can I solve it without installing anything in the system? 
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you could use free [Portable Python](http://portablepython.com) to run your script instead of cx_freeze. There currently is a Python 2.7 version.

Comment: Thank you for the response but I need to use the executable file that I get with cx_freeze. Any other idea?

Comment: Well, the other commonly used utility is [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/). However it, too, requires the msvcr90 C runtime DLL, and likewise, if you don't have it, getting it will require a separate install. See [Bundling the C runtime DLL](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step521).

Comment: The latest version of cx_Freeze has an `include_msvcr` option ([docs](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe)) that you could try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you eveyone for your help. I finally get it working with a different solution.

I found other programs in my system that has this dlls too. Eclipese was one of them (in this path:

> eclipse\plugins\com.intland.hgbinary.win32_2.3.2\os\win32

)so I just took:

> Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest
>
> msvcm90.dll
>
> msvcp90.dll
>
> msvcr90.dll

this files and copy and paste them to the folder of my compiled python code. And it works like magic.

Thank you anyway for your help!! :D

Comment: your experience may be help for me.